# Perform vector operation on dataframe of coordinates

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I currently have a data frame storing separate x,y,z coordinates from an accelerometer sensor (with timestamps), but want to perform vector operations on it.

Test data (actually have thousands of rows, and a timestamp row to be preserved)

```
x <- c(1,3,1,0,3)
y <- c(2,4,8,8,9)
z <- c(0,1,1,2,0)

df <- data.frame(x,y,z)

proj <- function(a,b) {
  as.double((a %*% b) / (b %*% b)) * b
}

v = c(1,2,3)
```

I want to mutate (or create a new dataframe?) `df` by applying `proj(_,v)` on each row.

I have tried along the lines of `mutate(projected = proj(c(x,y,z), v)`, but doesn't work, I am probably misusing this.

What is the best way to achieve this? Should I instead be using a list of vectors to store the coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

While your `proj(a,b)`-function does only take two inputs, in your example you wanted to provide three `proj(c(x,y,z),v)` or did I misunderstand?

However, this would work:
`dplyr::mutate(projected = proj(x,y), df)` resulting in

```
  x y z projected
1 1 2 0 0.4279476
2 3 4 1 0.8558952
3 1 8 1 1.7117904
4 0 8 2 1.7117904
5 3 9 0 1.9257642
```